# Generally Fizzy ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm, fizzbuzz

Given the following variables
divisor_array, low, high define a method that

1. Prints all numbers from low to high
2. If the any number being printed is divisible by any divisor number in `divisor_array`, print the number + the word "fizzy"
3. If the number being printed is divisible by ALL the numbers in the array, it should output the number + "reallyfizzy".

Testing Values: `generally_fizzy([2,3],1,7)`

My initial solution:

```
def generally_fizzy(divisor_array, low, high)
    divisors = Hash[*divisor_array]
    low.upto(high) do |i|
        divisors.each_pair do |k,v|
            if((i % k == 0) && (i % v == 0))
                puts "#{i} reallyfizzy"
            elsif ((i % k == 0) || (i % v == 0))
                puts "#{i} fizzy" 
            else
                puts i 
            end          
        end
    end
end
```

this solution passes the tests given, but when the `divisor_array` size is increased from 2 values to 3 and over it prints out duplicates. In addition to that, the code is not very elegant.

Looking for a working alternative, that can deal with `divisor_array` size changes.

Comment: Why are you checking pairs instead of just values one by one?

Comment: Homework or a tutorial?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just count how many divisors in the array will divide the value. There are three cases we care about:

- all of them
- at least one of them
- none of them.

```
def fizzy(divisors, lo, hi)
  lo.upto(hi) do |value|
    puts case divisors.count{ |div| value % div == 0 }
         when divisors.length      # all divisors
           "#{value} really fizzy"
         when 0                    # no divisors
           value
         else                      # at least one divisor
           "#{value} fizzy"
         end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

this is a little bit modified answer. It uses one exit point from method which i find more readable and robust (can be optimized if performance is a concern).

```
def fizzy(divisors, low, high)
  low.upto(high) do |value|
    print "#{value} "
    print "really" unless divisors.detect{ |div| value % div != 0}
    print "fizzy" if divisors.detect{ |div| value % div == 0}
    print "\n"
  end
end

fizzy([2,3],1,7) #=>
1 
2 fizzy
3 fizzy
4 fizzy
5 
6 reallyfizzy
7
```